# split with regex is not returning correct repsonse

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string

```
var str3 = "[a,b,c] there [s,b,c] how are u";
```

What i want is `[there, how are u]` but I am getting `["", "how are u"]`, when splitting with `str3.split(/\[.*\]/);`

Any idea how i shud do it?

Comment: its because your regex matches entire section `[a,b,c] there [s,b,c]` instead of just `[a,b,c]`

Comment: Your `\[.*\]` pattern matches `[a,b,c] there [s,b,c]` and thus remove this substring and puts an empty string and the rest of the string into an array. Use a non-greedy (also called "lazy") quantifier, `*?`, instead of `*`. You may remove empty matches by adding `.filter(Boolean)` to the split result. Also, to split with whitespace, too, at the same time, use `.split(/\[.*?]|\s+/).filter(Boolean)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be greedy:

```
str3.split(/\[.*?\]\s*/);
```

:-)

Comment: do point me to the duplicate, I will close this @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Sorry, didn't know it's a duplicate... What do you suggest to do with duplicates?

Comment: Should I better delete my answer?

Comment: You cannot delete accepted answers. Once the question is eligible for removal I will cast a delete vote.